# Get an NPM react build error that don't exist

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have a strange problem with NPM RUN BUILD. It reports an error that does not exist and I don't know what to do now. I can't `npm run build` because as the image below show, this error is not true I check source files and it's so strange:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are viewing the right version of this file? Or double check if you have this file opened with multiple editor. Or try to close the editor and terminal and then retry.

Comment: I restart laptop and open cmd and run the npm run build. I dont know why this is happening it feels like some cache need to be flushed or something reinstalled. It's like a ghost in the machine the source files does not have this

Comment: This is so strange. Also, you don't have another SnackbarItem.tsx with lowercase `s`?

Comment: As [this screenshot show](https://snipboard.io/fnRm5q.jpg) the code is not what npm run build is complaining about

Comment: Please supply the error in text format - it is easier for people to use text than images.

Comment: Suddenly it went away I dont know how